# Select box with possibility of adding new record

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I have a select box with various options. You can text something and it automatically searches for matches. If there are no matches found, I would like to create something like "+" button, where you can add a new record, and in fields below specify it. So I want to search my database, and if not found, to add a new record. I haven't got much experience with jQuery, but I think that there lays the solution.

[image: Select box]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this would be helpful

1. you can create new button just next to select box and keep this hidden.
2. when value not matched then you can show it and once user click on this buttn push searchbox value in your database so that for next time it would be available.

Answer (score 0):

On click of add button you need to do ajax call to add new data to database.
Once it is added you need to create new option and need to append it to your select field..
Following code snippet may help you

```
function addDataToDatabase(value_to_be_add){
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url : 'addToDatabase.php',
  data:{data:value_to_be_add},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    if(data['success']=='true'){
        var new_option = '<option value="'+data['id']+'">' + value_to_be_add + '</option>';
        $('#select_field_id').append(new_option);
    }else{
      alert("fail to add to database");
    }
  }
});
```

}

data['id'] : is id of data added with this ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

based on search criteria, search param ure sending to server, if data is not found that will return empty object. based on empty response, just enable hidden add (+) button and after clicked on add button selected new value will stored in database and in success response highlated the input value using below code

```
function SelectElement(val)
{    
    var el= document.getElementById('selBox');
    el.value = val;
}
```